# R labels in 3D barplots (lattice/latticeExtra)

Tags: r, 3d, label, lattice

I want to create an image as in Panel B, where the red numbers give the ranking of the bars. My code below allows me to generate panel A. **How do I have to adjust the code below so as to give the red labels in Panel B?**

[image]

**R-Code (for Panel A)**: Reproducible example code

```
# load necessary libraries
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

# create dataframe
df.test <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=9, ncol=4))
names(df.test) <- c("x", "y", "z", "z.rank")

# fill dataframe
df.test$x <- factor(rep(c("X1", "X2", "X3"), times=3), levels=c("X1", "X2", "X3"))
df.test$y <- factor(rep( paste0("Y", 1:3), each=3), levels=c("Y1", "Y2", "Y3"))
set.seed(2); df.test$z <- abs(rnorm(9, 0, 1))

# labels (rankings of z, from largest to smallest)
df.test$z.rank <- as.numeric(rank(df.test$z))


# plot 1 (bars)
p1. <- cloud(z~x+y, data=df.test, panel.3d.cloud=panel.3dbars, 
            ylab="Y", xlab="X", zlab="Z",
            xbase=0.2, ybase=0.2, scales=list(arrows=FALSE, col="black", distance=1),
            par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")),
            screen = list(z = 35, x = -35, y=0),
            alpha.facet = 1.00, border = "transparent",
            zoom=1.00); 
print(p1)
```

Comment: Please, do not duplicate your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393691/r-lattice-latticeextra-combine-barplot-with-textplot-labels-not-properly-dis